# Sort Git commit history affecting 2 branches

Tags: git

Starting from this commit history, with two local branches `a` and `b` not pushed to origin:

```
C1 - C2 - C3 - C4 - C5
          |         |
          a         b
```

I want to end in this situation, where C2+C5 is a commit after C5 has been squashed into C2:

```
C1 - C2+C5 - C3 - C4 
              |   |
              a   b
```

The problem is that doing an interactive rebase both `a` and `b` branches diverge and there is no way to end in the above situation.

To do the change I have to remove `a` branch  and recreate it after the rebase is performed. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you define "a **better** way"? Do you mean clearer? Faster? Something else?

Comment: I'm  wondering if there is a way that  allows to avoid having to remove and recreate branches.

Comment: My idea of the simplest way could be the same as yours. Maybe consider adding to your question the not-simple-enough-yet series of command you're about to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things to know here<sup>1</sup> as you go in:

1. You can't actually change any commits.  Internally, even Git can't do that.  What Git must do here is to make *new* commits.
2. Each commit has a unique "number": its hash ID.  The new commits will have their own unique numbers, different from the old (still-extant) commits, which will remain in your repository for at least a little while.
3. A *branch name*, like your `a` or `b` here,<sup>2</sup> just remembers the raw hash ID of the *last* commit in some sequence.  In your case, `a` is the last commit in your `C1-C2-C3` sequence, and `b` is the last commit in your `C1-C2-C3-C4-C5` sequence.

So what really happens is that you start with ... well, I'm going to draw the commits using single uppercase letters, rather than `C1`, `C2`, etc., which means I'll change the branch names as well, to `branch-a` and `branch-b`.  We start with this:

```
A--B--C   <-- branch-a
       \
        D--E   <-- branch-b
```

We now keep original commit `A` but make a new commit `F` that is the result of turning `B` into changes (by comparing `B` vs `A`), and turning `E` into changes (by comparing `E` vs `D`), and combining those changes and applying them all to the snapshot in commit `A`:

```
  F   <-- HEAD
 /
A--B--C   <-- branch-a
       \
        D--E   <-- branch-b
```

(This uses Git's "detached HEAD" mode internally, during the rebase process, hence the use of the special name `HEAD` to locate commit `F` directly.)  Having made this new commit, Git now has to copy existing commit `C` to a new commit `G`, by comparing `C` vs `B` to see what changed and applying those changes to `F`.  The result is:

```
  F--G   <-- HEAD
 /
A--B--C   <-- branch-a
       \
        D--E   <-- branch-b
```

New commit `G` is where you'd like the name `branch-a` to point in the end, so let's keep on copying commits—there's one left to copy—to turn `D` into `H` but draw it up one more step:

```
       H   <-- HEAD
      /
  F--G
 /
A--B--C   <-- branch-a
       \
        D--E   <-- branch-b
```

That's the heart of the rebase process, for *any* kind of rebase: it copies commits, one at a time, as if by `git cherry-pick`.  The *interactive* style rebase simply lets you take the set of `pick` commands—the individual cherry-pick instructions—and modify them to change the order or combine commits.<sup>3</sup>

In any case, having done the copying, the last few steps of `git rebase` involve yanking the branch name around to point to the last-copied commit.  In this case, that's new commit `H`, resulting from cherry-picking old commit `D`.  The special name `HEAD` identifies this commit right now, so Git runs the equivalent of:

```
git branch -f branch-b HEAD
```

to force the name `branch-b` to point here:

```
       H   <-- branch-b, HEAD
      /
  F--G
 /
A--B--C   <-- branch-a
       \
        D--E   [abandoned]
```

Then, Git re-attaches `HEAD` to the branch name, exiting the detached HEAD mode that it uses internally during rebasing:

```
       H   <-- branch-b (HEAD)
      /
  F--G
 /
A--B--C   <-- branch-a
       \
        D--E   [abandoned]
```

and now you see what you saw that prompted your question: *is there some way to make Git move the name `branch-a` while it's doing all this?*

The answer to that is no.  Git *does* now have a fancier version of `git rebase -i`, which you invoke with `git rebase -r`.  To make this fancier version work, Git has internally added all<sup>4</sup> the tools it would need to make this a reality—but there's still some more work to do, to glue the tools together in a usable way.  So for now, after you've done your `git rebase -i`, use [eftshift0's final `git branch -f` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63956186/1256452) from his answer.  That forcibly moves the other branch name, so that we get:

```
       H   <-- branch-b (HEAD)
      /
  F--G   <-- branch-a
 /
A--B--C
       \
        D--E   [abandoned]
```

Since the name `branch-a` is never actually *deleted* here, its reflog retains the fact that it used to point to commit `C`, just as `branch-b`'s reflog retains the fact that it used to point to commit `E`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, there are even more things to know, but these are the three I'll call out, because they're particularly relevant.

<sup>2</sup>In general, it's wise to avoid building branch names with the digits `0` through `9` and/or letters `a` through `f` without also adding at least one other letter outside this range, or a hyphen, or something.  The reason is that the commit "numbers" are spelled in hexadecimal, as a big ugly string like `e9b77c84a0a0df029f2a3a8114e9f22186e7da24`.  This is composed entirely of characters from that `[0-9a-f]` set.  If you keep the name short—three characters or fewer—you're "safe", so the branch names `a` and `b` themselves are fine, as are `cab` and `bed`.  But once you get to four or more letters, such as `cafe` or `deaf` or `decade`: well, now Git may try that name as an *abbreviated hash ID*.

If a name works as one or more abbreviated hash IDs, that name can be considered ambiguous: did you mean the name, or the hash ID that that name is short for?  Since the letter `r` cannot be in the set, the branch name `beer` is fine, but `beef` could be ambiguous.

In practice, this is rarely a problem,<sup>5</sup> and if you hit an ambiguous case and Git treats it incorrectly, just spell out a longer version of the name: the branch name `beef` is really `refs/heads/beef`, which you can abbreviate to `heads/beef` if typing `refs/heads/beef` is too much.

<sup>3</sup>You can do more than just these two, of course.  With some extra effort that Git *could* perhaps make a bit easier, you can split a commit into multiple separate commits.  You can drop commits entirely.  You can have Git run commands after a copy step.  But these are the two you're using at the moment.

<sup>4</sup>Or maybe "most": the label commands get us most of the way there, but depending on things I'm pretty sure others have considered but nobody has yet implemented, it's not clear whether we might want one or two new script-level commands for this too.

<sup>5</sup>There just aren't that many words that are spelled with these.  After "cafebabe" and "deadbeef", one has to get into 133t-5p34k or something.  I came up with a fake headline though: FADED ABACA DEFACE CAFE FACADE.

Answer (score 1):

You do an interactive rebase to reorder/squash

```
git checkout b
git rebase --interactice C1
# in the editor you move C5 right after C2
# you set C5 to squash
# leave C3 and C4 with pick after C5
# save and let it run
# when rebase is finished:
git branch -f a b~
```

And that's it